Attributes are not exported when using feature to polygon in ArcGIS Pro
When exectuing a feature to polygon task, the attributes are not copied to the new file.

Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour]

Please [edit] your Question to include the following information: a) The type of features you're converting to polygon, b) the steps you followed to run the tool, c) any other information that can make it clearer to potential answerers about your problem and possible solutions.

According to Feature To Polygon (Data Management) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation:

The output attributes will vary depending on the Preserve attributes parameter value and the Label Features parameter value.

But more importantly:

Note:
It is recommended that you do not use the Preserve attributes parameter, as it is no longer supported and does not work. It will remain, however, for backward compatibility of scripts and models. While the output attribute schema and field values for certain input combinations may be produced as described below, most of them are unintended.


Hi @bixb0012 thank you for you answer, could you explain to me how I can preserve the attributes?

@NWSP without further description of your data what you ask makes little sense. review the illustration for the tool, taking the line example as an example. It creates polygons from enclosing lines, what ruleset would YOU use to assign which attributes to which polygons? See the problem?
